# Reusing styles for children of a panel in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I am using Silverlight 5, and in one of my pages I have a StackPanel whose children I style in the following manner:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed"></Setter>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
<TextBlock Text="TextBlockText:"></TextBlock>
<Button Content="FirstButton" Command="{Binding SetLayout}" CommandParameter="FirstOnly"/>        
<Button Content="FirstSecondButton" Command="{Binding SetLayout}" CommandParameter="FirstSecond"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I have another StackPanel in the same page, how can I reuse this style without copy and pasting it all over again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options. Put it in the `Object.Resources` of both of their parents like `Window.Resources` or `UserControl.Resources` or whatever the case may be. Except this will effect all the objects of the same type within that parent.

Another way would be to do the same thing, if you dont want that, give each style template an `x:Key` name and call it explicitly to each instance like `<Buttton Style="{StaticResource YourExplicitStyleKeyName}"/>`

Or you can put the styles in a `ResourceDictionary` and call them explicitly the same way as mentioned above. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I'm sorry it's been a long time for me to reply although your answer was prompt. The first option unfortunately does not produce the effect I want, and the second option is something I want to avoid because it means I have to paste the attribute on every child attribute.

Comment: The third option looks good, but I ran into some trouble implementing it. What I did was I created a ResourceDictionary in the UserControl.Resources tag of the main page and gave it a key called x:Key="StackPanelResources" then I set the Resources attribute of the stackpanels to {StaticResource StackPanelResources}. However I get a runtime exception telling me that an object with key/name "StackPanelResources" cannot be found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, a `ResourceDictionary` is generally a separate file all together you would use to centrally allocate all your templates you want available globally throughout your application. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: So you are saying that there is no way to style the TextBlock children of certain stackpanels in a page without pasting rather lengthy XAML in each StackPanel declaration I want to style? If you are quite sure there is no way, I'll be glad to mark the question answered.

Comment: Well it depends on how you're formatting all your elements. If for example you want all the children of those types within a single StackPanel to inherit those templates, then you can do it how you're doing. If you wish the Templates inherited to other elements you just put them higher on the Parent of those items. However if there's only a few elements in each panel that require those templates then it makes more sense to just declare those styles with unique x:Key names at the outermost parent and declare them implicitly with Style="{StaticResource blah}" at the instance level, otherwise....

Comment: like you said, you'll end up with a bunch of reiterated style templates pasted all over the place. It ultimately relies on the overall layout as to what makes the best choice to handle the delegating of what objects either inherit, or are implicitly set with those templates. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Yes it does, but it is kind of disappointment I guess because it is rather less powerful/versatile than what CSS offers. I kind of assumed that styling options would be stronger with Silverlight.